# Position layer over two rows without offset

Tags: css, html

How do I layer a logo so that it overlaps the second row without shifting the page down? I'm using the Foundation framework http://foundation.zurb.com/ for a dynamic site. Foundation uses rows and I want to set up two rows:

- ROW ONE: Contains a logo
- ROW TWO: Contains an image (a slider to be exact)

I want the logo in row one to overlap row two but when I try to do that, it creates a 'padding' or space on top and I'd like the logo to sit tight to the top of the screen.

Here's the CSS I'm using for the logo:

```
.logo { 
    position: relative; 
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
    z-index: 10;
    }
```

And the CSS for the Foundation "grid":

```
.row { width: 940px; max-width: 100%; min-width: 768px; margin: 0 auto; }
.row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 0px; }
.row.collapse .column, .row.collapse .columns { padding: 5px; }
.row .row { width: auto; max-width: none; min-width: 0; margin: 0 -15px; }
.row .row.collapse { margin: 0; }

.column, .columns { float: left; min-height: 1px; padding: 0 3px; position: relative; }
.column.centered, .columns.centered { float: none; margin: 0 auto; }
```

I'm trying to do this without 'breaking' the dynamic grid.

One thing to note, row two is a "slider" and the CSS provides the following as a 'wrapper' but not sure how to use it:

```
.orbit-wrapper { width: 1px; height: 1px; position: relative; }
```

Finally, here's the HTML:

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="twelve columns">

   <img src="images/logo-200.png"; class="logo";>
</div> 

<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns">    
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="images/Main.png" =[img 1]" />
    <img src="images/Main-2.png" =[img 2]" />
     <img src="images/Main-4.png" =[img 3]" />
      <img src="images/Main-5.png" =[img 4]" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

SOLUTION:

Finally figured it out: key was to put the image I was trying to layer on top of the 'slider' in the same row as the slider and then use float:left. Here's the final HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="twelve columns"> 
<div style="float:left;">
<img src="images/logo-200.png"; class="logo";>
</div>
  <div id="slider">
    <img src="images/Main-01.png" =[img 1]" />
    <img src="images/Main-01.png" =[img 2]" />
     <img src="images/Main-01.png" =[img 3]" />
      <img src="images/Main-01.png" =[img 4]" />
  </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.logo { 
position: absolute; 
float: left;
left: 20px;
top: -90px;
z-index: 10;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From your HTML, At the moment you have a .row inside a .row, if this is OK, then

```
  .orbit-wrapper // should be encapsulating your #slider
```

If this is not ok, you should close the first .row div, and then correct the css selectors by adding a neigboor ~ between them :

```
  .row ~ .row
```

This way you have control on the first one and the following one.

Comment: OK, so I corrected the HTML - it's two rows, I should have closed the first row. But the problem isn't solved - what seems to be happening is that the row height is calculated by measuring the height of the logo, so that even though the logo shifts down to layer on top of the second row, it's still leaving a large blank section on top of the logo because the row is inheriting its height somewhere in the framework. I'll keep fiddling with it, maybe I'm misunderstanding what you mean by encapsulating with the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Added the answer to the 'question' section at bottom.